# Derivative of Quadratic form using chain rule

Tags: statistics, derivatives, vector-analysis

I want to differentiate
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( [Z^{\top} (y - X b)]^{\top} W [Z^{\top}(y - X b)] \right)
$$

Note that $b : K \times 1$, $y:G \times 1$, $X:G \times K$,$Z : G \times L$,$W:L \times L$.

I know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial b} A^{\top} x A = (A^{\top} + A)x$, but I can't apply that to chain rule.

How to solve that?

(This equation is needed to solve GMM in econometrics.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B := ZWZ^T$, then it should be obvious that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( [Z^{\top} (y - X b)]^{\top} W [Z^{\top}(y - X b)] \right) 
=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}  (y-Xb)^T B (y-Xb)
$$
Then, expand to get:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} [y^TBy - y^T BX b - b^T X B y + b^T X^T B X b
]$$
then, differentiate each term individually with respect to $b$ using standard rules as is listed on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) page.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p{\partial}$
Define the vector
$$\eqalign{
p &= Z^T(Xb-y) \quad\implies\quad dp = Z^TX\,db \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new vector and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= p^TWp \\&= W:pp^T \\\\
d\phi &= W:(dp\,p^T+p\,dp^T) \\&= (W+W^T):dp\,p^T \\
 &= (W+W^T)p:dp \\
 &= (W+W^T)p:Z^TX\,db \\
 &= X^TZ(W+W^T)p:db \\
 &= X^TZ(W+W^T)Z^T(Xb-y):db \\\\
\frac{\p\phi}{\p b}
 &= X^TZ(W+W^T)Z^T(Xb-y) \\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon has been used to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A}$$
The properties of the trace allow terms in such a product to be rearranged in many ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B = etc}$$